# Why am I getting all these nils - Euler 3

Tags: ruby, null

I came up with this solution for [Project Euler 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) although I got the answer I also get so many nils before it I can't figure out why? is there any way I can only get the answer.

Anyway here is my code

```
def factor(number)
    max = []
    (2...number).each do |x|
        if number % x == 0
            number = number/x
            max << number
            s = max[-2]
        elsif number == 1 
            return[]
        end
    puts s
    end
end
puts factor(600851475143)
```

Comment: Hint: what do you want to output (with `puts`) and what do you want the method return? These parts of your method is unclear.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with Ruby's [Prime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html) class, though I'm not advocating it's use for this exercise. Using the method [Prime#prime_division](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division), you could write: `require 'prime'; a = Prime.prime_division(600851475143) #=> [[71, 1], [839, 1], [1471, 1], [6857, 1]]; a.map(&:first).max
 #=> 6857` (or `a.max_by(&:first).first #=> 6857`).

Answer (score 0):

`max` is an empty array. `s = max[-2]` is `s =[][-2]` for a long time. `[][-2]` returns nil.